# Remote access Windows Home Premium

Tags: windows, networking, permissions

I have computer with Windows Home Premium.

I want to be able to have remote access to the files and folder shared by my computer.  How can I do that?

Comment: Can we just clarify what you are trying to do?  "Remote access" refers to viewing the screen of your remote computer on another machine, while just being able to access the files is something entirely different.

Comment: Where will you be accessing these files from? What type of router and modem setup do you have? Do you have access to these devices? Do you have a static IP with your ISP? These are all concerns that you will have to consider aside from just the method of remote access.

Answer (score 4):

The Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) server is not enabled in Windows Home Premium, and there is no easy and supported way to do so.  I have the same issue, and as far as I see it, there are two options:

1. Continue using [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx), [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) (or some other VNC solution)
2. Buy a Windows Anytime upgrade to Windows 7 Professional, which will add the RDP server.

Since the Professional edition adds support for backing up to network drives, and I have some usability issues with TeamViewer and UltraVNC, I'm personally leaning towards buying the Anytime upgrade.  However, the issues I'm experiencing may not affect you, in which case one of the solutions in the first option may be a viable free option.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access them through Windows' built-in remote desktop (only work on Professional and Ultimate editions) unless you use unsupported hacks.

However there are several other options, for instance VNC.

Comment: Any link to unsupported hacks?

Comment: well, use at own risk: http://www.missingremote.com/guide/how-enable-concurrent-sessions-vista

Answer (score 2):

Lifehacker has got an excellent article on the best remote tools:

> http://lifehacker.com/5080121/five-best-remote-desktop-tools